# Wordpress header and footer scale with viewport

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, viewport

I have a custom page where the table isn't responsive and looks like this on mobile:

[image: Website after load]

It's okay for me, but I want to header and footer scale as well. Now it's looks like in the `header.php`:

```
<?php if (is_page(538)): ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`538` is the page id. I know if I remove these lines it'll work fine, but is there any other options to make it scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag should be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0" />
```

﻿﻿Also check your page ID: you have 538 in the code, but write about 528 (maybe just a typo)

Comment: yeah, typo, I fixed it